# Keras: freezing layers during training does not give consistent output

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to fine-tune a model using keras, according to this description: https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionv3
However, during training I discovered that the output of the network does not remain constant after training when using the same input (while all relevant layers were frozen), which I do not want.

I constructed the following toy example to investigate this:

```
import keras.applications.resnet50 as resnet50
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras import optimizers
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np

# data  
i = np.random.rand(1,224,224,3)
X = np.random.rand(32,224,224,3)
y = to_categorical(np.random.randint(751, size=32), num_classes=751)

# model
base_model = resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224,224,3)))
layer = base_model.output
layer = Flatten(name='myflatten')(layer)
layer = Dense(751, activation='softmax', name='fc751')(layer)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=layer)

# freeze all layers
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# features and predictions before training
feat0 = base_model.predict(i)
pred0 = model.predict(i)
weights0 = model.layers[-1].get_weights()

# before training output is consistent
feat00 = base_model.predict(i)
pred00 = model.predict(i)
print(np.allclose(feat0, feat00)) # True
print(np.allclose(pred0, pred00)) # True

# train
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=2, epochs=3, shuffle=False)

# features and predictions after training
feat1 = base_model.predict(i)
pred1 = model.predict(i)
weights1 = model.layers[-1].get_weights()

# these are not the same
print(np.allclose(feat0, feat1)) # False
# Optionally: printing shows they are in fact very different
# print(feat0)
# print(feat1)

# these are not the same
print(np.allclose(pred0, pred1)) # False
# Optionally: printing shows they are in fact very different
# print(pred0)
# print(pred1)

# these are the same and loss does not change during training
# so layers were actually frozen
print(np.allclose(weights0[0], weights1[0])) # True

# Check again if all layers were in fact untrainable
for layer in model.layers:
     assert layer.trainable == False # All succeed
# Being overly cautious also checking base_model
for layer in base_model.layers:
     assert layer.trainable == False # All succeed
```

Since I froze all layers i fully expect both the predictions and both the features to be equal, but surprisingly they aren't.

So probably I am making some kind of mistake, but I can't figure what.. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check if X is changed (maybe shuffled) by fit generator? There is a big chance, because the generator will create/load data instead of just using your random X.

Comment: You can test if the same happens with `model.fit(X,y,batch_size=2,epochs=3)`.

Comment: That sounds plausible, I will try it as soon as I get home tonight!

Comment: I did as you suggested but it did not change the result.. I edited the question with some more tests. Using a different input for testing I demonstrate that before training the output is consistent but after training it changes..

Comment: Are you sure you are disabling training for all layers in `base_model`, too? maybe `model.layers` doesn't include them and they remain trainable.

Comment: Yes, I edited the example with an assertion add the end that checks if all layers in the model are untrainable. This assertion does not fail, so this was the case.

Comment: Have you found an answer/work around yet? I'm running into the same bug.

Comment: No I still haven't found any solution..

Comment: Ok @Perm.Questiin , I think I found the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seems to be that the model uses batch normalization layers, which do update their internal state (i.e. their weights) based on the seen data during training. This even happens when their trainable flag have been set to False. And as their weights are thus updated, the output also changes. You can check this by using the code in the question and changing the following codelines:

This `weights0 = model.layers[-1].get_weights()`
to `weights0 = model.layers[2].get_weights()`
and this `weights1 = model.layers[-1].get_weights()`
to `weights1 = model.layers[2].get_weights()`
or the index of any other batch normalization layer.

Because then the following assertion will no longer hold:
`print(np.allclose(weights0, weights1)) # Now this is False`

As far as I am aware there is currently no solution for this yet..

See also my [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8372) on Keras' Github page.

Answer (score 0):

One more reason for unstable training could be since you are using a very small batch size, i.e., `batch_size=2`. At least, use `batch_size=32`. This value is too small for the batch normalization to compute reliably the estimation of the training distribution statistics (mean and variance). These mean and variance values are then used to normalize first the distribution and followed by learning of `beta` and `gamma` parameters (actual distribution).

Check the following links for more details:

1. In the **introduction** and **related works**, the authors criticized BatchNorm and do check **figure 1**: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08494.pdf
2. Nice article on "Curse of Batch Norm": https://towardsdatascience.com/curse-of-batch-normalization-8e6dd20bc304